# How to save database in unique value

Tags: php, mysql

I need first warehouse id should be save 1 in database and next warehouse id should be increment by +1 and save 2. how to done this code. my code is only save same value again and again in warehouse id coloumn.

```
 <?php
//insert.php;

if(isset($_POST["item_des"]))
{
 $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");

 $ware_id = 0;

 for($count = 0; $count < count($_POST["item_des"]); $count++)
 {  
  $query = "INSERT INTO unloading 
  (warehouse_id,Item_Des, ItemSize, Quantity, Return_Items, Damage_Items) 
  VALUES (:ware_id,:item_des, :item_size, :item_quantity, :item_return, :item_damage)
  ";
  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':ware_id'   => ($ware_id) + 1,
    ':item_des'  => $_POST["item_des"][$count], 
    ':item_size'  => $_POST["item_size"][$count], 
    ':item_quantity' => $_POST["item_quantity"][$count], 
    ':item_return' => $_POST["item_return"][$count], 
    ':item_damage'  => $_POST["item_damage"][$count], 



   )
  );
 }
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 if(isset($result))
 {
  echo 'ok';
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Make the `id` an auto increment column in your schema

Comment: Remove this "':ware_id'   => ($ware_id) + 1," , from your php code and set the ware_id as auto-increment column at the database side.

Comment: Or you could try `':ware_id'   => ++$ware_id,`

Comment: i have already increment id section. i need another section of warehouse id. if i delete one of my warehouse id (ex - if delete last warehouse id 12 then next save should be last id 12) in auto increment if i delete 12 then next id save in 13.

Comment: @CashvillyAce The Id is used to identify a specific row in the table, specially for foreign key references. However, they are not used for "counting" rows. What are you trying to do and why is it important that the Id column has no "holes" or are in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id of the last row in the table (lets say `x`) and then initialize `$ware_id` with `(x+1)`.

Now, each time the loop gets executed you have to increment `$ware_id` by 1.